# Add meta noindex to post if it has a specific taxonomy

Tags: php, taxonomy, seo

How can I add the following line to the current post if the product_type = 'enviso_group_ticket'?

```
<meta name=”robots” content=”noindex,nofollow”/>
```

`product_type` is a default taxonomy of the Woocommerce product.

I already have the following:

```
$product_type = get_the_terms( $post->ID,'product_type')[0]->slug;
if($product_type == "enviso_group_ticket"):
  //add meta to header
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wp_robots](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_robots/) filter to manipulate the robots meta tag as needed. And as you're checking against a taxonomy term you can use the [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) helper conditional to make your code look a litte nicer. (*A post can be passed to `has_term()` as the 3rd parameter, but if it is not passed then the function checks against the current post.*)

```
add_filter(
    'wp_robots',
    function(array $robots) {
        if ( has_term('enviso_group_ticket', 'product_type') ) {
            return array_merge(
                $robots,
                array(
                    'noindex' => true,
                    'nofollow' => true,
                )
            );
        } else {
            return $robots;
        }
        
    }
);
```